# html pattern to parse in php

Tags: php, parsing, html-parsing

i have a following pattern, inside the html file, that i would like to parse in php to get a link but for now i dont see a solution as i am trying to use QueryPath and my case is simply not a common dom element:

```
<script>
to.addVariable("site_name","http://www.sitename.com");
</script>
```

I just would like to return a link part of that pattern in order to print it.

Hope someone could recommend how to.
Thank you.

***UPDATE:*** I would like to get http://www.sitename.com as a value from the code above using php, maybe with phpQuery or QueryPath.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question, please?

Comment: I would like to get http://www.sitename.com as a value from the code above using php, maybe with phpQuery or QueryPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this I guess will work

```
<?PHP
    $text = '
    <script>
    to.addVariable("site_name","http://www.sitename.com");
    </script>
    ';
    preg_match('#to\.addVariable\("site_name","([^"]+)"\);#', $text, $matches);
    echo $matches[1];
?>
```

You can also use `preg_match_all` if you have more than one `to.addVariable(...` strings in your `<script>` section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular exp:

```
$regex = '#to\.addVariable\("(.+?)", "(.+?)"\)#';
```

Then, use preg_match_all to get the matches. If you want to check that the URL is an **actual** URL, the get any regular expression to match URLs and place it in the second .+?, these patterns will match anything between "", so you should check that you have what you need unless you trust the source.

**NOTE:** I'm not so sure that " doesn't needs to be escaped in regex, so check it out

Hope I can help!
If you don't understand something drop a comment!

Comment: Would you kindly provide a small sample with preg_match and how to extract each var of the two (using result array indices 1 and 2) ? I think this would help the author.